# Java 1.4 Factory Question

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I have a factory, and I want to restrict the possible values that may be passed into the get method.

```
public static class FooFactory{

 public static final String TYPE1= "type1";
 public static Foo getFoo(String type){
   switch(type){
    case "type1":
      return new Type1();
    }
   }

 }
```

To use this:

```
FooFactory.getFoo(FooFactory.TYPE1);
```

I'd like to restrict the parameters that may be passed in. Is an idea to make a Type abstract class, then subclass and use Type as the parameter?

Comment: What kind of insane environment has you programming in Java 1.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't subclass it, just create a `Type` class with a private constructor that takes a stirng parameter, and define public `Type` constants.

Something like this.

```
public final class Type {

    public static final Type FOO = new Type( "foo" );
    public static final Type BAR = new Type( "bar" );

    private String type;

    private Type( String type ) {
      this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() { return type; }
}
```